# Create a branch with its origin path on a different remote repository

Tags: git, hook, branch

Good morning/evening

I have two repos A and B.
I'm writing a hook for push events, in some cases I want to create a branch in B based on A.

example:

in A i'm working on `main/release1.2/featureAAA/BugABC`
when i push in A if the push is ok I want to create the branch in repo B BugABC but in the same path `main/release1.2/featureAAA`.

If the origin branches does not exists in B just exit with an error message

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be on branch A first:

```
git checkout A
```

and then, you can make a new branch by:

```
git checkout -b B
```

Comment: Thank you. So in my my hook on A I should git checkout BugABC then i should git checkout -b B
but would that validate that B is in the exact same branch path ?

Comment: Yes, you can make a new branch with the same path from branch A

Comment: Thanks, so the command should be git checkout -b <URL_of_my_repo> ?

Comment: Don't go through the URL, but you have to go through your repo on the branch that you will equate, with the example branch A above.